# Why is NUnit hanging from the command line, but not under TestDriven.NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, nunit, testdriven.net

If I start my unit tests from TestDriven.NET under VS2008, they run pretty much immediately.

If I start my unit tests using `nunit-console.exe`, the NUnit console hangs for five minutes before actually running my tests. If I attach a debugger, it seems to be spending its time in `System.IO.MemoryStream.Read`, called from `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters`, called from `System.Runtime.Remoting`, on the other side of some native-managed transitions called by `NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Test.get`. Sometimes, it's in `System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RecordFixup` or `.FindObjectHolder`.

This is with NUnit-2.5.2 on 32-bit XP, fully patched. All assemblies are targeted to .NET 2.0.

What *is* `nunit-console` up to? Is there any way to persuade it to not do it?

Comment: How is your application configured? There's a long search list for configuration files, if it's getting insufficient or invalid configuration, it could be spending lots of time attempting to parse.

Comment: I wish I could remember: I'm now on VS2010, using a much later version of NUnit, and it all works.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but I would just give up and go with XUnit, it's really much better anyway.

Comment: Have you tried disabling shadow copy in nUnit console?

Comment: I think it's having a hard time communicating with nunit-agent. That's probably why you're having trouble with Remoting, and maybe kill an existing run of nunit-agent. Also try the /process Single that @wigy mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure, since I am also lucky to use a new version. You probably have a huge test suite with lots of tests, aren't you? If you do not need application domain isolation for other reasons, you can [turn it off](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assemblyIsolation&r=2.5.7) and then you save the remoting/marshaling time.

Try this please and give feedback to us how it went:

```
nunit-console.exe /noshadow /nologo /process Single /domain None whatever.dll
```

There is also a way to add these options via [the configuration files](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.5.7), if you do not want to touch your build scripts even with a stick. :)